# How to set 1d array to 2d array element in C

Tags: c, arrays, c99

I need something like this:

```
char font[128][8] = {{0}};

font[0][] = {0, 0b00000000, 0b11111100, 0b00010010, 0b00010010, 0b11111100, 0b00000000, 0};
font[1][] = {...}
```

But in c99 I get "expected expression before '{' token". Please help.

Comment: You can't assign to arrays. Either use initializer lists during initialization, or compound literals and `memcpy()`, or assign one-by-one in a loop.

Comment: Is `0b00000000` valid in C ?? Help please..

Answer (score 1):

You can only use an initialiser list (`{...}`) when declaring the array, that's why you're getting an error. You can't assign a value to an array, which is what `font[0]` is (a `char[]`).

You have 3 options:

- ```
  char font[128][8] = {
    {0, 0b00000000, 0b11111100, 0b00010010, 0b00010010, 0b11111100, 0b00000000, 0};
    {...}
   }
  ```
- Assign each value to an element in the array individually: `font[0][0] = x`, ..., `font[127][7] = y` (ie. using a loop).
- `memcpy` blocks at a time from like a `uint64_t` (`sizeof(font[0]) = 8`) or wherever else you can neatly/efficiently store the data.

It's probably also worth noting that binary constants are a C extension, <strike>and that `char` is signed</strike> and if you're working with unsigned data you should probably explicitly use `unsigned char`.

Comment: Wait, what? `char` is signed? Since when? In my version of C, whether or not `char` is signed is a completely implementation-defined decision.

Comment: @ElchononEdelson: Oh yeah you're right, it should be *could*.

Answer (score 0):

```
char font[128][8] = {
    {0, 0b00000000, 0b11111100, 0b00010010, 0b00010010, 0b11111100, 0b00000000, 0},//font[0]
    /*{...}*///font[1]
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it out :

```
    char font[128][8] = {{0}};  
    char a[8] = {0, 0b00000000, 0b11111100, 0b00010010, 0b00010010, 0b11111100, 0b00000000, 0};
    //Take array a to store values 

    for(int i = 0;i<8;i++)
    font[0][i] =  a[i];
    //Assign value of a to font
```